# Performance impact of using async await when its not necessary

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Let's assume I have these methods:

```
public async Task<Something> GetSomethingAsync()
{
    var somethingService = new SomethingService();

    return await service.GetAsync(); 
}
```

and

```
public Task<Something> GetSomethingAsync()
{
    var somethingService = new SomethingService();

    return service.GetAsync();  
}
```

Both options compile and work the same way. Is there any best practise as to which option is better of if one is faster then the other?

Or is it just some syntactic sugar?

Comment: The first option waits for the task to complete, but the second doesn't. So the second is going to be much faster.

Comment: @Enigmativity, both methods will returns to the caller in same time. But in second method responsibility for "awating" task will be moved to the caller. While in first approach code execution will be returned back when Task is comleted.

Comment: @Enigmativity no, both return a task with identical behaviour

Comment: @Fabio no, caller gets back exactly the same thing from both: a `Task<Something>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first method compiler will generate "state machine" code around it and execution will be returned to the line `return await service.GetAsync();` after task will be completed. Consider example below:

```
public async Task<Something> GetSomethingAsync()
{
    var somethingService = new SomethingService();

    // Here execution returns to the caller and returned back only when Task is completed.
    Something value = await service.GetAsync(); 

    DoSomething();

    return value;        
}
```

The line `DoSomething();` will be executed only after `service.GetAsync` task is completed.

Second approach simply starts execution of `service.GetAsync` and return correspondent `Task` to the caller without waiting for completion.

```
public Task<Something> GetSomethingAsync()
{
    var somethingService = new SomethingService();

    Task<Something> valueTask = service.GetAsync(); 

    DoSomething();

    return valueTask;        
}
```

So in the example above `DoSomething()` will be executed straight after line `Task<Something> valueTask = service.GetAsync();` without waiting for completion of task.

Executing `async` method on the another thread depend on the method itself.

If method execute `IO` operation, then another thread will be only waste of the thread, which do nothing, only waiting for response. On my opinion `async - await` are perfect approach for `IO` operations.

If method `GetAsync` contains for example `Task.Run` then execution goes to the another thread fetched from thread pool.

Below is short example, not a good one, but it show the logic a tried to explain:

```
static async Task GetAsync()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Iterate GetAsync: {i}");
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}

static Task GetSomethingAsync() => GetAsync();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task gettingSomethingTask = GetSomethingAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("GetAsync Task returned");

    Console.WriteLine("Start sleeping");            
    Thread.Sleep(3000);            
    Console.WriteLine("End sleeping");

    Console.WriteLine("Before Task awaiting");
    gettingSomethingTask.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("After Task awaited");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And output will be next:

```
Iterate GetAsync: 0
GetAsync Task returned
Start sleeping
Iterate GetAsync: 1
Iterate GetAsync: 2
Iterate GetAsync: 3
Iterate GetAsync: 4
Iterate GetAsync: 5
End sleeping
Before Task awaiting
Iterate GetAsync: 6
Iterate GetAsync: 7
Iterate GetAsync: 8
Iterate GetAsync: 9
After Task awaited
```

As you can see executing of `GetAsync` starts straight after calling it.

If `GetSomethingAsync()` will be changed to the:

```
static Task GetSomethingAsync() => new Task(async () => await GetAsync());
```

Where `GetAsync` wrapped inside another Task, then `GetAsync()` will not be executed at all and output will be:

```
GetAsync Task returned
Start sleeping
End sleeping
Before Task awaiting
After Task awaited
```

Of course you will need to remove line `gettingSomethingTask.Wait();`, because then application just wait for task which not even started.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to make sense:) One comment though - the "async" in the second method of yours is not necessary at all since you are not calling "await" anywhere in the body.

Comment: Am I missing something? I think; In the second example, the `valueTask` isn't executed at all. Until you `await`  or `valueTask.Start()` etc..

Comment: Thats a good point as well.. I'm really confused by all this. I thought it would be something simple.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, as I mentioned in the answer behavior of the returned `Task` depend on the code inside `GetAsync`.